# Symfony, how to set session timeout in action

Tags: session, symfony1, timeout, symfony-1.4

How to set session timeout in symfony 1.4 from an action?

Comment: Why do you want to set the session timeout in an action? This seems a bit inappropriate. Please give some background info.

Comment: Admin needs to change it in admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   sfConfig::set("sf_timeout", (int)SettingsQuery::getAttr("session_timeout", 42000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `timestamp parameter` to the session when its created. Then in your actions just check this timestamp is not too old.

Good luck